# remove text/table entry 'shipping & handling' everywhere in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, totals, customer-account

I was able to remove it from the checkout page. But it is still in the my order review page as well as the print version of the order. So far I didn't find it anywhere else. But is there a way to not show it in the frontend?

I changed Shipping.php and totals.phtml (all of them) but no matter what I commented or tried had any influence on it. Where do I have to change this?

Comment: ok, did it. I just thought, answering my own question isn't very welcome around here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to disable it. In `\Mage\Sales\Block\Order\Totals.php`, I commented the part around line 107:

`/**
  * Add shipping
  */
  if (!$source->getIsVirtual() && ((float) $source->getShippingAmount() || $source->getShippingDescription())) {
    $this->_totals['shipping'] = new Varien_Object(array(
      'code'  => 'shipping',
      'field' => 'shipping_amount',
      'value' => $this->getSource()->getShippingAmount(),
      'label' => $this->__('')
    ));
  }`

Now it's gone for good.